# Foobar2000 on linux

Tags: linux, music, foobar2000

Does anyone successfully run Foobar2000 on linux ( under Wine ) ? Are there any alternatives with a similar philosophy, and maybe even with the ability to use the Foobar2000 plugins ?

Comment: on how to improve the looks of foobar2000 and other windows applications under wine - look at this answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/219795/47206)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of audio players on Linux that are similar to Foobar. You might like [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) or [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/).

However to get Foobar2000 running under wine, it looks like all you need to do is use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) to install needed fonts. [This forum](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=54933) has instructions.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. The forum link was helpful. I think it might be a bit outdated, but it's the best I could find too.

Answer (score 6):

[deadbeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/) is a nice little clone of foobar2000 for linux. Its got a very similar UI, and its own, admittedly limited plugin system - you can get plugins here [here](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/plugins.html) and installation instructions for those [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/118644/47206).) It does have the clean, basic layout I'm used to.

[image]

Comment: with the 'file browser' plugin, it can access a large media library and stay as light as before (and in this respect it behaves better than foobar, which gets somewhat heavier than before when monitoring a large music media library)

Comment: A good alternative, though the tag editor interface doesn't work with the keyboard as easily. Also, if you have trouble playing M4A files, [try adding `m4a` to the list of extensions that FFMPEG supports](https://github.com/DeaDBeeF-Player/deadbeef/issues/1663#issuecomment-256018360) (*Preferences **>** Plugins **>** FFMPEG audio player **>** Configure **>** File Extensions*).

Answer (score 4):

Amarok is the closest I found to Foobar on Linux.

There's nothing that can use Foobar plugins that I know of.

I haven't run it under Wine personally but [people have reported it seems to work pretty well.](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1749)

Answer (score 2):

foobar2000 works perfectly in Wine, with addons.

Regarding fonts/appearance, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/219791/47206) - for Linux alternatives, [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/38970/47206).

---

More recently, foobar2000 is [available as a snap in Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/foobar2000).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about [snaps](https://www.fossmint.com/what-are-ubuntu-snaps-and-how-are-they-important/) to endorse this method (and haven't even tried it myself), but apparently you can get [foobar2000 on Linux via SnapCraft](https://snapcraft.io/foobar2000).  It must use Wine under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly with PlayOnLinux as well, which is easier to setup than Wine (provides macros and scripting for needed component install).

The only complication that I experienced was setting up a network drive mapping, which must be done with CIFS in order to have Foobar see my network shares correctly.  If you are using local storage this is not an issue.