# How to tidy music mp3 files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management, mp3, music-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-tagging MP3s](https://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s)

I have thousands of MP3 files and it is really messy all over place. Some in drive E and F. There are a lot of duplicates files in many different folders and incorrect/messy file names and even missing tags.

I am looking for a way to clean it all up and move music files in a folder with albums folders and fix file names, tags, etc. To get all organised and tidy?

Which software could do this?

Comment: See also: [How to organize music?](http://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music/87794#87794), [What application do you use to play and manage music on your computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/12627/what-application-do-you-use-to-play-and-manage-music-on-your-computer/24049#24049) – most of the tools in the question linked to as the duplicate do auto-tagging and moving based on content though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/).  It will fix your tags and organize your files in a customizable tree.  The only thing I haven't been able to make it do is check and tag duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue and tried MusicBrainz "Picard".  While it did an okay job, there were still a number of songs (almost half my collection) that had either missing or incorrect tags.  In my experience, I found that there's really no substitute for going through your collection and updating this info manually.

I ended up using [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/).  It allows you search for & apply tag data from Amazon's database, to one or more songs.  It also allows you to embed the album art.